# Determine if a jQuery event has expired (event bubbling has ended)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

DOM events have three phases: capture, target, and bubble, and the `eventPhase` property of a DOM event reflects which phase the event is in.

jQuery events also have this property, but it doesn't seem to update as the event moves through its life-cycle. I think it's just be a snapshot of a DOM event at a particular time.

**Is there a way to determine from a jQuery event if the original event's life-cycle has ended without inspecting the original event?** (Inspecting the original event won't work for me since IE6-8 events don't have properties like `eventPhase` or `currentTarget` that can be used to determine if an event is still bubbling.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned its not supported in older versions of IE therefore jQuery will not help you for those cases anyways. So for now just use eventPhase on the original DOM event when it is available.

Comment: I was hoping jQuery had some other clever way of figuring it out, or perhaps there was an IE method I wasn't aware of.